# how to use nosql RavenDB with php or rails or django?

Tags: php, django, ruby-on-rails-3, ravendb

how to use **RavenDB** with **PHP** application or **Rails** application or **Django** application ???

Answer (score 2):

You can access RavenDB via its [HTTP API](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/http-api).